# Generic solution for SQL Server 2008 collation conflict issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, collation

We have migrated our SQL server 2000 DB to SQL server 2008.After migration we are facing collation mismatch issue with 500 stored procedures. I can understand the issue occurs due to different collation levels of the DBs.It can be solved on modifing 500 SPs or changing the collation level of the DB.But I cannot afford either of the solutions. Is there any generic solution for the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you migrate a database by backing it up and restoring it, it will maintain its collation as well as the collation for all objects it contains, so that in itself will not cause a problem if you do it for all databases. If you migrate by scripting objects and copying over data, then you might have a problem -- so don't do that, or else make sure to check the option "script collations" when you use the "Generate Scripts" task (this is under "Set Scripting Options -> Advanced" in my version of Management Studio).

Even if the collation on all of your databases are correct, you can then still have conflicts with the system databases, which, in turn, can be solved by changing the server collation, either through [the procedure described in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms179254), or (simpler and safer) reinstalling SQL Server and selecting the appropriate collation, using the same collation as the SQL Server 2000 instance used.

If you can't change the server collation or you're unwilling to (as the newer collations supported in 2008 *are* better), another option is to change the collation of the databases giving the conflicts. In this case, you *do* want to migrate by scripting the database and copying over data, this time making sure to *not* script collations so the database ends up with the server default collation.

In all cases, changing the server or database collation has no effect on existing objects. Only newly created objects (and rebuilt objects) will end up with the new collation. Changing collation after the fact is a pretty big undertaking that you want to avoid if at all possible, but [this article](http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/seven-step-process-changing-database-collation) describes how to do it if it's necessary.

Comment: Note that changing the server collation doesn't change a user database's collation, and changing a DB collation doesn't change existing column collations. You may be required to drop indexes, keys, functions, etc. when changing database collation. You'll then need to update collation on each table column, too, including views, potentially.  [Here's](http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/seven-step-process-changing-database-collation) a good overview of the procedure of changing a user DB's collation.

Comment: @BaconBits: right you are -- I've taken the liberty of incorporating your remarks into the answer.